# Cannot insert struct into set: “no match for operator<”

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, set

I was trying to learn to use sets that contain a struct, but ran into a strange problem.

Here is the code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct Course {
    string name;
    string theme;
    int enrollments;
};



int main()
{

    Course test_course1 = {"English", "Language", 5};
    Course test_course2 = {"Spanish", "Language", 4};
    Course test_course3 = {"Spanish", "Language", 10};

    set<Course> test_set;

    // This is what causes the issues. If I block the following three lines of code, the program runs perfectly.
    test_set.insert(test_course1);
    test_set.insert(test_course2);
    test_set.insert(test_course3);


    map <string, set<Course>> test_map;
    test_map.insert({"London", test_set});
    test_map.insert({"New York", test_set});
    test_map.insert({"New York", test_set});


    for (auto i: test_map)
    {

        cout << "In  " << i.first << " there are following courses " << endl;

        for (auto x :i.second){
            cout <<x.name << endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The issue?
I've take a screenshot of all the issues that appear if I try to insert the struct Course into a set:
[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIl15.jpg)

P.S. I know that that test_course2 and test_course3 are almost identical. I'm just testing...

Comment: Screenshots are unreadable. Please paste the error message as text.

Comment: A std::set is an ordered structure. However, struct Course has no operator< so std::set does not know how to order the instances of Course.

Comment: An `std::set` of elements, being a binary search tree, *requires* `<` for that type of element to be defined, because otherwise it has no idea how to insert them.

Comment: Alternatively: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648480/how-can-i-create-a-stdset-of-structures You can't expect the compiler to do magic. A compiler is stupid and it doesn't guess how to sort your struct.

Comment: @mfnx Could you please code a visual example that would show what it is that should've been done differently? I know what an operator is but in this context I don't quite follow...

Comment: @churill That's a much better dupe, thanks :) I made it the first target.

Comment: @Pepesaurus Please spend some time reading the dupes, and trying out the suggestions there. I'm confident that will address your concerns.

Comment: @churill I see, that was pretty helpful. Thank you! Now, knowing this, let's say I want courses to be ordered based on the name of the course in alphabetic order but I am not allowed to make any changes to the struct itself. How would I go about doing this? How would the code look like in this context? While the linked information was very good, I don't quite grasp this quite yet.